# xdotool: moving window "above" 0 0

Tags: command-line, xorg, xdotool

As per the title. When I do

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 0 0 windowsize 1200 $height_first_monitor
```

`xdotool` moves the window. But when I do

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove -40 0 windowsize 1200 $height_first_monitor
```

I get a `windowmove: unrecognized option '-40'`

Google searches for "xdotool move above 0 0" and "xdotool move negative" and similar did not yield any useful results.

Comment: I guess developers didn't even implemented moving out of window borders. Because when you move window to the right far beyond resolution, you still get window aligned to the right border. `xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 10000 0`

Comment: Try `65496` instead (relying on 16 bit overflow). It works for me with relative movements. The final position of the window is forced fully onscreen for me, not sure who and why does it.

Comment: Nitpicking: `-40 0`, if worked, would be to the left. Above is `0 -40`.

Comment: @desert sure. i have a Firefox that needs to be vertically fullscreen but horixontally not (because i mirror part but not all of my screen on a kindle)

Answer (score 4):

This would seem to be a bug, but from so long ago it might now be called a *feature*. To use negative numbers in certain places you will need to add the *end-of-arguments marker* `--`.  For example, you can do

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 0 -10
```

but you need to do

```
xdotool getactivewindow windowmove -- -10 0
```

This is because windowmove can take optional arguments `--sync` and `--relative`, but also (probably for backwards compatibility) the same with a single dash: `-sync` and `-relative`. Sadly, `-10` is then mistaken for such an (unexpected) argument.

Looking at the [sources](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/blob/master/cmd_windowmove.c#L52) for windowmove, you can see it uses the standard C library function [getopt_long_only()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt_long_only). This function looks for long arguments that begin `--` or `-`.
The alternative `getopt_long()` would just look for `--` long arguments.

I'm not sure if the above link is to the definitive sources, but this feature seems to be around from before 2010.

Comment: Hats off, nice finding!